# Javascript format array with regex youtube video ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, youtube

Apologies in advance as I know there are so [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714739/javascript-regular-expression-for-extracting-youtube-video-ids) to this question however I have not been successful with implementing any of the given answers. With that being said, let's get to the issue.

I have a table containing text inputs where user enters youtube video ids

Onsubmit my javascript will create an array containing these youtube video ids

If user enters a youtube url, the array breaks

**Quick Solution**

If someone can help me get the regex validation to work so the user will be alerted properly and correct their input that would be a good start

**Ideal Solution**

I'm not fond of alerting users and making them change what they've entered as its bad user experience so if anyone is feeling extra helpful today and could show me how to take what they enter and strip out the url bits and push only the youtube video id to the array that would be super wonderful :)

example: if user entered

```
["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1CScQOj1dA", "https://youtu.be/wIJ1sFrgMds", "IISzG-sPUuo"]
```

the code would format their inputs and the final `userSongs` array would be:

```
["K1CScQOj1dA", "wIJ1sFrgMds", "IISzG-sPUuo"]
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1qLr9n2j/
As you can see, the alert says no match when two of the inputs are invalid entries

Comment: Why `(new RegExp('\\b' + userSongs.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b'))`?

Comment: I found that solution here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219960/javascript-match-against-array

Comment: You just want to transform `userSongs` array?

Comment: Yes I'd preferably like to transform the array and not have to alert the user. Whichever solution is easiest.

Comment: Check out the answers here and customize this for your use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
.*?([\w-]+)$
```

And replace with `$1`.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/7)

JS Code:

```
var rx = /.*?([\w-]+)$/;
for (var i = 0; i < userSongs.length; i++) {
        userSongs[i] = userSongs[i].replace(rx, '$1');
}
alert(userSongs);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I put this into my if statement?

Comment: Wow! How did you reduce the regex from `/^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?v(?:i)?=|\&v(?:i)?=))([^#\&\?]*).*/` only down to `/.*?([\w-]+)$/` ? :)

Comment: [check your code](http://jsfiddle.net/uapc7hh4/).. thats because you are dealing only with `ids` and not the actual url pattern..

Answer (score 1):

Here's my crack at the **Ideal Solution**

```
var re = new RegExp("youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)/(?:.*v(?:/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)");

$('.song-input').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val()
    if (val) {
        var matches = val.match(re);
        $(this).val(matches[1]);
    }
});
```

I took the regex from James Poulson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717252/1818) to the question you linked to.

Comment: Looks awesome, but I'm getting an `Unexpected token }` error when I put this in my fiddle. Advice?

Comment: Hmm, I actually copied and pasted this from a Fiddle myself; must be unclear exactly which part this is intended to replace? Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/1qLr9n2j/2/

Comment: Ok thanks. I see it changing the input values. So in your fiddle should I just add `userSongs.push($(this).val());` to line 19 before the } get my formatted array now?