# Regex validation for youtube url - field is optional returns as required

Tags: c#, regex, forms, validation, youtube

I am working on using a validation expression to authenticate valid youtube urls. What I have does the job well except in IE it comes up as required when I need it as optional.

I did some research and tried an alternate method but it still come sup as required in IE.

[C# regex to get video id from youtube and vimeo by url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652046/c-sharp-regex-to-get-video-id-from-youtube-and-vimeo-by-url)

below is what I am using currently.

```
<label for="you_tube">Video (Your YouTube URL):</label>
<asp:TextBox placeholder="YouTube URL to your Video" runat="server" ID="you_tube" MaxLength="150" /><br/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExYouTube" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Format should follow: http://youtu.be/8-qxGN4VWzY or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33aZX7qxgcw" CssClass="formError" ControlToValidate="you_tube" ValidationExpression="http(s)?://(www\.)?(youtu\.be|youtube\.com)[\w-/=&?]+"  Display="Dynamic" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents on msdn lead me to believe this should work... Anyways, a simple work around is to modify your current regex (`currentRegex|^$`) to accept an empty string in addition to the two accepted url formats.

Another solution can be found here; http://forums.asp.net/t/1657041.aspx/1

To summarize, you start with the validator disabled, then enable it when the TextChanged event is fired.